# Any idea why hackerrank doesn't accept my code even if it prints exactly what is asked

Tags: python

The staircase is right-aligned, composed of # symbols and spaces, and has a height and width of n
Here is the exact question from hackerrank:
https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/staircase/problem

And here is my code:

```
#!/bin/python3

import math
import os
import random
import re
import sys

# Complete the staircase function below.
def staircase(n):
    for i in range(-1,n):
        print(n*' ' + (i+1)*'#')
        n=n-1

if __name__ == '__main__':
    n = int(input())

    staircase(n)
```

Comment: There are n test cases in hackerrank and similar , probably your code doesnt work with some special cases. If your code is working with given example this does not necessarily mean that it will work with all other examples

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an extra line of spaces on the top 
Try this-

```
import math
import os
import random
import re
import sys

# Complete the staircase function below.
def staircase(n):
    for x in range(1,n+1):
        print((n-x)*" "+"#"*x)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    n = int(input())

    staircase(n)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using python3:
Try following for the same problem (All test cases should pass):

```
#!/bin/python3

import math
import os
import random
import re
import sys

# Complete the staircase function below.
def staircase(n):
    num = n
    for i in range(1,n+1):
        space = num-i
        if space==0:
            print("#"*i)
        else:
            print(' ' * (space-1), "#"*i)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    n = int(input())
    staircase(n)
```

Comment: It works, Thank you but what is wrong with my code? @webDev

Comment: One extra space in-front of the output lines.

Comment: No, I tested and it doesn't print space at last line. Just as it is wanted @webDev